# Voryx Rest Bundle Symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms, fosrestbundle

So I'm using voryx bundle to create a rest api for my symfony2 application.

https://github.com/voryx/restgeneratorbundle

I have two questions, first is how to create a post request for many to many relationships

Also is it okay to turn of crsf?